# Create a Conditional Statement in R studio

Tags: r, regex

I have a data set which has columns like name, second name,full name and telephone number.
I would like to create a statement that returns Telephone numbers of people with second names beginnings with letter below "P".

I created a `data.frame` that has letters

```
   df <- data.frame(L=letters[1:26])
   > class(df)
   [1] "data.frame"
   > class(phonebook)
     [1] "data.frame"
   > class(phonebook$name)
     [1] "factor"
   > class(phonebook$secondname)
     [1] "factor"
   > class(phonebook$fullname)
     [1] "factor"
   > class(phonebook$TelpNum)
     [1] "numeric" 
   EXAMPLE DATA
   name          secondname      fullname     TelpNum

   Sage           Kafka          Sage Kafka   234234234

   CUP           Ripley          CUP Ripley   12312325
```

It has to return to row that starts with "Sage":

> ```
> Sage           Kafka          Sage Kafka   234234234
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grep`, with pattern `^[A-O]`, meaning "start with letter in the range of A..O":

```
phonebook[grep('^[A-O]', phonebook$secondname),]
```

To add more conditions, for example that `TelpNum` is not NA,
use `grepl` instead:

```
phonebook[grepl('^[A-O]', phonebook$secondname) & !is.na(phonebook$TelpNum),]
```

Comment: I am also  trying to find names that has not have a phone number by changing your statment                                                                                         '> phonebook[grep('[NA]', phonebook$TelpNum),]'                                       it returns                                                                                                        [1] name       secondname fullname   TelpNum   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) but value set has NA values what is the problem?

Comment: Because of the columns data.type?